# What is the right way to hard-code some methods and fields of particular instances of a model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a site that pulls feeds in from various sites. Most of these are via RSS, but a few are via API, like HackerNews. I have a `ListView` that shows all of my feeds, so I want to keep all of these the same type of model.

What I'm looking to do is this (does not work):

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    rss = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_feed_data(self):
        # return data based on self.rss


class HackerNewsFeed(Feed):
    name = "Hacker News" # Doesn't work

    def get_feed_data(self):
        # Return data based on Hacker News API
```

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975909/django-model-instance-specific-code) seem to say that I should simply use the `Feed` model with custom methods based on the name...then I would manually input "HackerNews" into the database and this would automatically trigger my API code. It feels a little hacky.

What is the best way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Not related, but `//` is not the python comment syntax. I fixed them in your post, try to use `#` next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Feed` is a `models.Model` you can only assign model fields as class parameters. Assigning `name = "Hacker News"` won't work on models. Since it doesn't look like the *shape* of the data needs to change depending on the feed type, then just leave your model as-is, and implement your feed fetching based on the `self.name` attribute. Something like this:

```
# assumes a file called `feedfetcher.py` in the same 
# directory as your `models.py` file
from . import feedfetcher

class Feed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    rss = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_feed_data(self):
        return feedfetcher.fetch(self.name)


# feedfetcher.py

def fetch(name):
    if name == 'Hacker News':
        # get hacker news feed
    elif name == 'Reddit':
        # get reddit feed
    else:
        # we have no fetcher for this
        # kind of feed yet.
        raise ValueError('No fetcher for {}'.format(name))
```

If you add too many feeds this will quickly become unruly. I would probably split RSS feeds into a common method or class to make handling of those automatic. Add the following attribute to your model:

```
feed_type = models.CharField(choices=(('RSS', 'RSS'), ('API', 'API'))
```

And then you could check what the feed type is within `get_feed_data` and if it's RSS, hand off to a specific RSS feed handler. I'm assuming each API will be different though, so you can keep the `fetch` method above to figure out and call each individual API.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting the fixed Feeds using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) and then make `get_feed_data` conditional based on `name`.

```
def get_feed_data(self):
    if self.name == "Hacker News":
        # Return data based on Hacker News API
    else:
        # return data based on self.rss
```